# Pygame: objects moving one by one

Tags: python, loops, object, pygame

I'm creating a tower defense game using pygame. And the functions to spawn and move enemy's work fine. However, the next enemy only moves when the first enemy is done moving. I assume this has something to do with the `for` or the `while` loop. Who can correct my code so that the objects move simultaneously.

This function is called in the main loop of the game:

```
# creates and places all of the enemys
def begin_wave(self):
    # mark next waves as started
    self.wave += 1
    print("Wave number: ", self.wave)

    ### Draw Enemy ###
    for enemy in self.enemies:
        while enemy.waypoints_reached < len(config.WAYPOINTS):

            # Move enemy
            enemy.move()

            # Paint game + new enemy location
            self.paint(self.screen)

            # Update Screen
            pygame.display.update()

    # if done -> set state to BA_CLEAR
    print("Wave Completed!")
    self.waves_comp += 1
    self.state = config.BA_CLEAR
```

The first function which is needed is the move enemy function which is this one:

```
def move(self):

    speed = config.DEFAULT_SPEED

    # Update enemy's location
    if self.get_position()[0] < self.trackNextWaypoint()[1]:
        if self.trackNextWaypoint()[1] - self.get_position()[0] >= speed:
            self.set_position((self.get_position()[0] + speed, self.get_position()[1]))
        else:
            self.set_position((self.get_position()[0] + (self.trackNextWaypoint()[1] - self.get_position()[0]),
                       self.get_position()[1]))

    if self.get_position()[0] > self.trackNextWaypoint()[1]:
        if self.get_position()[0] - self.trackNextWaypoint()[1] >= speed:
            self.set_position((self.get_position()[0] - speed, self.get_position()[1]))
        else:
            self.set_position((self.get_position()[0] - (self.get_position()[0] - self.trackNextWaypoint()[1]),
                       self.get_position()[1]))

    if self.get_position()[1] < self.trackNextWaypoint()[2]:
        if self.trackNextWaypoint()[2] - self.get_position()[1] >= speed:
            self.set_position((self.get_position()[0], self.get_position()[1] + speed))
        else:
            self.set_position((self.get_position()[0],
                       self.get_position()[1] + (self.trackNextWaypoint()[2] - self.get_position()[1])))

    if self.get_position()[1] > self.trackNextWaypoint()[2]:
        if self.get_position()[1] - self.trackNextWaypoint()[2] >= speed:
            self.set_position((self.get_position()[0], self.get_position()[1] - speed))
        else:
            self.set_position((self.get_position()[0], self.get_position()[1] - (self.get_position()[1] - self.trackNextWaypoint()[2])))

    # If enemy position is on waypoint
    if self.get_position()[0] == self.trackNextWaypoint()[1] and self.get_position()[1] == self.trackNextWaypoint()[2]:
        self.setWaypointsReached(1)
```

Finally, these functions might also be needed for you understanding:

```
def trackNextWaypoint(self):
    for waypoint in config.WAYPOINTS:
        if waypoint[0] == self.waypoints_reached+1:
            return waypoint
            break

def setWaypointsReached(self, number):
    self.waypoints_reached += number

def get_position(self):
    return self.position

def set_position(self, position):
    self.position = position
```

Update

---

And I've also got an [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/hitz2j) for your visualisation

Comment: I'm not a pygame user, but from a quick look I think the problem could be that you call display.update() inside the for loop, for every enemy movement. Try moving it outside of the for

Comment: @klutt well, I think it does not really work the way it should, because the enemies move one by one, how to can I move them together, step by step

Comment: @JonasGiuro I'll try

Comment: Try the solution from @JonasGiuro cause it seems sensible

Comment: problem is you use `while` inside `for`. Inside `for` every object has to do only small step - it will only need `if` to check object position. And `for` should be inside some `while` loop which have to somehow check if it still need to execute `for` to move objects with small step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because you use `while` inside `for`.

Object inside `for` should make only small step and external `while` should execute `for` many times.

You need some method to check if all objects are moved to destination and repeat again `for` loop.
I use `how_many_moved` to check if all enemies are in destination.

It could be something like this

```
# value bigger than 0 to start `while` loop
how_many_moved = 1

while how_many_moved > 0:

    how_many_moved = 0

    ### every enemy makes only small step ###
    for enemy in self.enemies:
        if enemy.waypoints_reached < len(config.WAYPOINTS):
            # count how many was moved
            how_many_moved += 1

            # Move enemy
            enemy.move()

            # Paint game + new enemy location
            self.paint(self.screen)

    # Update Screen afer every enemy made small step
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: That did the job! Thanks